# Strong params and action mailer issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have tried to create a mailer using the following code:

routes code

```
resources :listings do
  member do
    put :lead
  end
end
```

mailer controller code

```
  def lead(listing)
    @listing = listing
    mail(to: @listing.leadrecepient, subject: "test")
  end
```

standard controller code

```
  def lead
    Enquiry.lead(@listing).deliver
  end
```

view

```
<%= form_for lead_listing_path(@listing), method: :put do |listing| %>
  <%= listing.text_field :name %>
  <%= listing.submit %>
<% end %>
```

In the context of a business directory, I want it so that there is a enquiry form on each listing page that when filled out and submitted, the information is sent to the relative listing email.

The problem however is that when I type into the form and click submit, I get the following error:

```
param is missing or the value is empty: listing
```

This seems to be because I have it in the "listing" controller which controls the showing and creation of the business listing itself. I therefore have strong params for a new listing which contains all the new listing variables:

```
  def listing_params
    params.require(:listing).permit(:fullname, :jobtitle, :email, :franchisename, :leadrecepint, :shortdescription, :longdescription, :website, :branchcount, :scale, :mininvestment, :investmentrange, :category, :hexbg, :logourl, :facebook, :twitter, :linkedin, :googleplus, :approved)
  end
```

How do I go about fixing this? I'm a beginner if I'm honest, could really do with some help to get this mailer working! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Strong params are for when you are submitting new resources or modifications to resources.  To protect against people adding extra parameters that may circumvent security or other aspects of your application unexpectedly.

If you are adding an action to an existing resource that the user is authorized to access, which this appears to be, you want to just find the object by ID, and use it.  So instead of finding it using the params filtered through `listing_params`, just find it like this in the controller:

```
def lead
  listing = Listing.find(params[:id])
  Enquiry.lead(listing).deliver
  redirect_to listing
end
```

And invoke it using a simple link, instead of this:

```
<%= form_for lead_listing_path(@listing), method: :put do |listing| %>
  <%= listing.text_field :name %>
  <%= listing.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Just use this in your view:

```
= link_to 'Go!', lead_listing_path(@listing), method: :put
```

Nothing more to it.

Comment: Thanks Nick, with = link_to 'Go!', lead_listing_path(@listing), method: :put as the new view code, how do I build the form fields?

Comment: What form fields do you need?  It doesn't seem like you're submitting anything for this controller method.